# How to Read URL param and body typing in Fast API Python

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, python-typing

I want to create a generic endpoint definition in Fast API Python that reads URL path parameter and then calls a specific method to do a derealisation.
But I always get

`422 Unprocessable Entity`

So I expect that it works like so:

/answer/aaa -> handle_generic_answer -> read_item_aaa, type body to ModelAAA

/answer/bbb -> handle_generic_answer -> read_item_bbb, type body to ModelBBB
etc.

Here's the generic endpoint code:

```
@app.post("/answer/{type}")
def handle_generic_answer(type: str, item):
# I also tried 
# def handle_generic_answer(type: str, item: Any):
# or
# def handle_generic_answer(type: str, item: Optional):
    switcher = {
        'aaaa': read_item_aaa,
        'bbb': read_item_bbb,
        'nothing': unrecognised_answer
    }
    func = switcher.get(type, unrecognised_answer)
    print('answer >> ' + type)
    func(item)
```

then I have separate methods called based on a `type` value:

```
def read_item_aaa(item: ModelAAA):
    update_aaa(item)
    return {"type": "aaa", "result": "success"}

def read_item_bbb(item: ModelBBB):
    update_bbb(item)
    return {"type": "bbb", "result": "success"}
```

and a default -

```
def unrecognised_answer(type):
    print("unrecognised_answer")
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="answer type not found")
    return {}
```

models are defined like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class ModelAAA(BaseModel):
    field1: str
    field2: list = []
```

But whether I call

http://localhost:8000/answer/aaa

or http://localhost:8000/answer/some-other-url

I always get 422:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "query",
                "item"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to annotate body parameter `item`.

Without this `item` is treated as query `str` parameter. For example:

```
@app.post("/answer/{type}")
def handle_generic_answer(type: str, item: Union[ModelAAA, ModelBBB]):
```